# Alphanumeric Sorting using SQL Server / C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have alphanumeric numbers. After applying sorting thru SQL Server `ORDER BY` clause, I get following result

```
select * 
from WO
where WOCode = AnyNumber
order by [ColumnName]
```

Result:

```
39660A1
39660A10
39660A11
39660A2
39660A3
39660A4
39660A5
39660A6
39660A7
39660A8
39660A9
```

Required result

```
39660A1
39660A2
39660A3
39660A4
39660A5
39660A6
39660A7
39660A8
39660A9
39660A10
39660A11
```

Comment: By `Sorting thru SQL server` do you mean an `ORDER BY` clause?  Are you looking for a C# answer or a SQL answer?  What have you tried?  Where do we start?

Comment: yes i mean order By Clause. SQL or C# anything is fine

Comment: There is still very little to go on - what is being sorted?  You will want to research *Natural Sort* - many good answers here

Comment: Where is the SQL statement you used?

Comment: I updated my Question ,, I was trying to BOLD 39660A10 and 39660A11

Comment: unfortunately you lose the line breaks unless you format as code and then the markup for bold doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
ORDER BY LEN(Field) ASC, Field ASC
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba613a/6/0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the letter `A` is always in the same position, and the characters after it are *integers only*.

Then you can do this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        WOCode,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(WOCode, CHARINDEX('A', WOCode) + 1, 
                       LEN(WOCode) - CHARINDEX('A', WOCode) + 1) AS INT) AS DisplayOrder
    FROM 
        WO
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DisplayOrder;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edd35/8)

Results:

```
|   WOCode |
|----------|
|  39660A1 |
|  39660A2 |
|  39660A3 |
|  39660A4 |
|  39660A5 |
|  39660A6 |
|  39660A7 |
|  39660A8 |
|  39660A9 |
| 39660A10 |
| 39660A11 |
```

You can also use [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) to avoid errors that might result because of using cast with non integer values (Thanks to @zambonee for suggestion):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        WOCode,
        CASE 
           WHEN TRY_CAST(WOCode AS INT) IS NULL 
              THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(WOCode, 
                          CHARINDEX('A', WOCode) + 1, 
                          LEN(WOCode) - CHARINDEX('A', WOCode) + 1) AS INT) 
              ELSE 0 
        END AS DisplayOrder
    FROM  
        WO
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DisplayOrder;
```

[updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edd35/13)